# Diagonal entries of an Hermitian matrix are real

Tags: matrices

A matrix $A$ is *Hermitian* if $A=A^*$ where $A^* = (\bar A)^T$. I read in a book that the diagonal entries of every hermitian matrix is real. I really can not understand why it is true.

Thanks

Comment: The diagonal entries are their own conjugates, so they must be real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each is equal to its complex conjugate.

Comment: I just started learning Linear Algebra, would you please explain  a bit more. thanks

Comment: Whyt do you mean by *each*, here?

Comment: The question is about the diagonal entries of a hermitian matrix, so when I write «each» I mean «each diagonal entry».

Answer (score 4):

Take a simple example of a 1-dimensional complex matrix: $[a+ib]$.
To be hermitian, you need to show that $[a+ib]=\overline{[a+ib]}=[a-ib]$, hence $b=0$.

Comment: huh, free downvotes for all?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This example is easy and correct.

Answer (score -1):

When you take the transpose, the diagonal entries will not change the position. Then after taking the conjugate, the diagonal entries should be the same. That means they must be real.